# How to map CURSOR to Map in iBatis

Tags: java, oracle, ibatis

I'm wondering if is there possibility to map first row from Oracle Cursor to java.util.Map (using column names as keys) in iBatis version 2.3.4.726. I came up to with TypeHandlerCallback:

```
public class MapResultTypeHandler implements TypeHandlerCallback {

    @Override
    public void setParameter(final ParameterSetter parameterSetter, final Object o) throws SQLException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getResult(final ResultGetter resultGetter) throws SQLException {
        ResultSet resultSet = resultGetter.getResultSet();
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int columnsNumber = metaData.getColumnCount();
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>(columnsNumber);

        do {
            for(int i=1; i <= columnsNumber; ++i) {
                result.put(metaData.getColumnName(i), resultSet.getObject(i));
            }
        } while (resultSet.next());

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Object valueOf(final String s) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately method getMetaData throws:

```
UnsupportedOperationException("CallableStatement does not support this method.");
```

Is there other possibility to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to map Oracle Cursor to Map! I had to modify first row of getResult method. It should look like:

```
ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) resultGetter.getObject();
```